# numerical precision vs .net framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, precision, .net-standard

In our project we have a calculation dll written in C#.

Before it was build for in `.Net 4.7.2`

Now it is build in `.NetStandard`.

Since the migration, we observe little differences in last decimals of outputs.

Would you say that these varying parameters are a good explanation to the numerical differences observed ?

I am quite sure that depending on execution CPU architecture and the .Net framework used, the `double` actual number of bytes inside bus (?) or cpu (?) is not the same and this could influence the precision on the result of some numerical algo.

---

EDIT : two apps to use this dll, one in `.Net 4.7.2` and one in `.Net-core 2.1`. We see numerical differences in the first one before/after the migration, and also between the two apps.

Comment: What is the framework used by your application? Is it .NET Core 3.1? .NET Standard is not a framework. Anyway, this might explain what you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781786/net-core-3-yields-different-floating-point-results-from-version-2-2

Comment: @MartinLiversage thanks for the link :) , it is this kind of thing that I suspect...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.net core 3 yields different floating point results from version 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781786/net-core-3-yields-different-floating-point-results-from-version-2-2)

Comment: @IanKemp : your link is on the similar topic. But the issue we have on our project is difference when a DLL compiled in 4.7.2 vs netstandard is called by a process in 4.7.2 or core-2.1. Actually I suspect as we compile in AnyCpu the calling project that depending on the DLL compilation, the true execution is in x86 when the DLL is compiled in 4.7.2 and vs x64 when compiled in netstandard. This is a cheap guess. I was looking for users with similar experiences to workout this point. The question reformulated would be then "does netstandard favor x64 execution while net 4.7.2 favors x86 ?"