# ToString has a different behavior between .NET 462 and .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am migrating an application from the `.NET Framework 4.6.2` to `.NET Core 3.1` and my unit tests failed in a place I did not expect.

After some calculations, I ended up with a `double` with 16 digits. According to the debugger, I got the exact same value whether I am running the `.NET462` or the `.NETCore31` code. The difference occurs when I "serialize" this value. In the `.NETCore31` version, the last digit is lost:

Here is an exemple:

> .NET

```
4.0584789241077042.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
// "4.0584789241077042" (the exact same number)
```

> .NET Core

```
4.0584789241077042.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// "4.058478924107704" (the last digit is gone)
```

It is not actually an issue, my calculation does not require such precision, but **does anyone know why I am getting two different results?**

Comment: .NET Core improved floating points a lot. Check out the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781786/net-core-3-yields-different-floating-point-results-from-version-2-2) as I think it will answer your question

Comment: I'm not sure the linked answer does answer this question -- this question has the number of digits *decreasing* on newer versions of .NET Core

Comment: @canton7 and yet you provided "answer" that links to the same article and cites the same portions of the article...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did use the same source, but that answer focusses on versions prior to .NET Core 3.0 producing strings which couldn't be roundtripped. That isn't the case with this question, where the result of `ToString("R")` can be round-tripped just fine prior to .NET Core 3.0. While that other answer does quote "ToString("R") will now return the shortest roundtrippable string", it doesn't explain how this applies to OP's question. I tried to expand a bit on the "shortest roundtrippable string" bit more, by showing that `"4.058478924107704"` is parsed back to `4.0584789241077042`

Comment: Big changes in CoreCLR since Feb 2019.  It used to be implemented in C++, inside the CLR, using either 15 or 17 significant digits.  Now written in C#, producing the shortest possible through the Grisu algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many changes to floating-point were made in .NET Core 3.0, which [Tanner lists in this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0).

I think the one that concerns us is:

> `ToString()`, `ToString("G")`, and `ToString("R")` will now return the shortest roundtrippable string. This ensures that users end up with something that just works by default. An example of where it was problematic was `Math.PI.ToString()` where the string that was previously being returned (for `ToString()` and `ToString("G")`) was `3.14159265358979`; instead, it should have returned `3.1415926535897931`. The previous result, when parsed, returned a value which was internally off by 7 ULP (units in last place) from the actual value of `Math.PI`. This meant that it was very easy for users to get into a scenario where they would accidentally lose some precision on a floating-point value when the needed to serialize/deserialize it.

So your value of `4.0584789241077042` is now round-tripped as the shortest value which can be roundtripped. In other words, even though the resulting string is missing the last decimal place (`"4.058478924107704"`), parsing that back to a double still gives `4.0584789241077042`, due to the fact that the closest value to `4.058478924107704` which can be presented by an IEEE double is `4.0584789241077042`.

```
double original = 4.0584789241077042;
Console.WriteLine("Original: {0:G17}", original);
// Original: 4.0584789241077042

string s = original.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("Rouble-trippable: {0}", s);
// Rouble-trippable: 4.058478924107704

double parsed = double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("Parsed: {0:G17}", parsed);
// Parsed: 4.0584789241077042

Console.WriteLine("Original == Parsed: {0}", original == parsed);
// Original == Parsed: True
```